How to Join a Task and Schedule to Associated Jobs in Tableau REST API using C#?
I'm currently working on integrating Tableau with our system using the Tableau REST API and C#. Specifically, I'm trying to join a task and its schedule to their associated jobs.
Here is what I have so far:
var client = new RestClient("https://YOUR_TABLEAU_SERVER/api/3.9");
var request = new RestRequest("/sites/YOUR_SITE_ID/tasks/extractRefreshes", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("X-Tableau-Auth", authToken);
var response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    var tasks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskResponse>(response.Content);
    // Further processing to join tasks and schedules to jobs
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.ErrorMessage);
}

I've managed to get the list of tasks and schedules separately, but I'm struggling with the correct approach to join these to their associated jobs.
My questions are:

How can I join the extract refresh tasks and schedules to their associated jobs using the Tableau REST API?
Are there specific API endpoints or C# libraries that would facilitate this process?

Thanks!
